# WPF ListBox: Vertical scrollbar and focus

Tags: wpf, listbox, wrappanel

I have two problems regarding a ListBox/WrapPanel.

First of all, my setup:
In XAML I have a ListBox. Inside of the ListBox is a WrapPanel. Programatically I add ListBoxItems to the WrapPanel.

**Problem one**

The ListBoxItems [StackPanel with Image and TextBlock] fills left to right and up to down. However, a vertical scrollbar does not appear if there are more ListBoxItems than there is space in the ListBox. The following XAML code makes the vertical scrollbar visible. However, it remains disabled:

```
<ListBox Name="li1StandortLinks" Background="Transparent" MaxHeight="300" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <WrapPanel Name="wp1StandortLinks" ItemHeight="80" ItemWidth="150" Width="755" />
</ListBox>
```

How to get a functional vertical scrollbar when needed?

**Problem two**

When clicking into the ListBox but not at a ListBoxItem [for example, in between two of them], the background of the whole ListBox gets highlighted in blue. Initially the background is transparent and it should remain like this even if the ListBox itself was clicked. Catching the Click-Event and setting the background back to transparent seems not to help. The blue highlight-color does disappear, but instead of the ListBox background going back to transparent, it then remains grey.
Can I change the style so that the color does not change at all when clicking at the ListBox? I never really changed styles in WPF, though, so I'd need a precise explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work for problem one :

```
    <ListBox Name="li1StandortLinks" Background="Transparent" MaxHeight="300" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

for problem 2 :
this may work too (change style for your listbox)

```
<ListBox Name="li1StandortLinks" Background="Transparent" MaxHeight="300" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

<ListBox.Style>
 <Style  TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hello Ahmad,

problem 2 is solved by your suggestion indeed, thank you for that! :)
Problem 1 is not solved unfortunately. I adapted the code to your suggesstion but it only added a second scrollbar which is also disabled.
I wonder why the WrapPanel creates a horizontal scrollbar if I do not limit the width but doesn't do the same thing for vertical direction.

Comment: You are welcome Kai ,I am sorry to hear that I have not used warppanel before but it's strange for me to put something inside the ListBox Content can I ask what your purpose of that ? may be I can help then

Comment: Sure thing. I want to achieve an explorer-alike look with the Items in my ListBox. They consist of an Icon and a Text which is dynamically loaded. I want to fill the icons from left to right and then up to down. A WrapPanel gives me this possibility. Adding the items only to the ListBox does only fill then in one direction [or, "dimension"], not in both.

Comment: Ah I got it then I think you have to use the warp panel as an itemspanel for the listbox not as a content I have corrected my answer above take a look at it and try to use it
please let me now if this solves the problem.

Comment: It works :))) Perfect. Thank you alot! Will mark your reply as answer!